# how to read/convert android .bpt files?

Tags: python, android, json

I want to convert a .bpt file I got from an andriod app (.apk) to something else; pandas, json or something else readable in python. As I understand it, it's a json-like format.

Do any of you know how it could be done?

I'm familiar with Python and R, but I'm open for every suggestion.

Would help me out a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide example of that file? There aren't much data online about `.bpt`. Are you talking about 'Belarc Product Key'?

Comment: It is some kind of data-file, but I cannot open it. It's probably encrypted, I just realized. Even though I'm still interested, I will not proceed with this further. Thank for looking at it, Alex!